# Java Code Debugging with step by step process highlighting with Eclipse

Tags: java

I saw this somewhere, but I don't know where. It was basically something in Eclipse that was a feature when debugging that highlighted the code as it went through the code. I need this because I have decompiled a huge library, and I need to know how specific features are created.

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Ughh ... reverse engineering decompiled code is pretty pessimal if you are doing legitimate software development.  If you can't you get source code, maybe you should ditch the "product" you are using in favour of something that is more developer friendly.

Comment: Oh, it's for creating a modification for a popular game. There are already people who've decompiled it and provided the source for it, though I'm trying to see if I can do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**F5** key : Executes the currently selected line and goes to the next line in your program. If the selected line is a method call the debugger steps into the associated code.

> More details in this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)